# Return values under a column if the value in anther column does not equal to zero

Tags: vba, excel-formula

So what I need to do is basically to return the values in column E to column I if the values under column G is non-zero. I was able to return all the non-zero values under column G to column K, but I not sure if I could retrieve the corresponding values under column E and F to I and J.

Is this something that could be done by a formula, or I have to use VBA?

Appreciate any insights! I've attached the sample here:

[image]

Comment: The way you intend to do has the risk of having 2 rows with the same balance. Are you only trying to remove the 0-values?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to just filter out the data that you currently have to not include zeroes.  But do it below the first table or on another worksheet

Comment: Kind of. Basically if the Ending Balance equals to zero, then I don't need the corresponding values in the same row under Vendor and Service. Thanks.

Comment: I can just filter it out but I am trying to automate the process. My actual worksheet is a large spreadsheet and ideally I need to generate a summary sheet with all non-zero balance with other related information each month.

Comment: @kira1031 - Then I would suggest a Pivot table

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about duplicated items on column G, you should be able to use a combination of INDEX() and MATCH():

```
=INDEX(E$1:E$7,MATCH($K1,$G$1:$G$7,0))
```

**If you have issues with duplicate values** use the following array formula (Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after editing the formula).

For Cell I1 use the following (drag it to cells J1 and K1):

```
=+INDEX(E$1:E$8,MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("g"&1+1):$G$8>0,0))
```

And for the rest, copy the following formula on cell I2 and drag it down and to the right:

```
=+INDEX(E$1:E$8,MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("g"&MATCH(I1,E$1:E$8)+1):$G$8>0,0)+MATCH(I1,E$1:E$8))
```

Comment: Yes, there are potential duplicate values under Ending Balance. That's is part of the what I am struggling with. Thank you though!

Comment: Check it now, the second section should work with duplicated values as doesn't rely on results of column K anymore